# Why was Python related question on SO closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Storing bytearray strings in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848880/storing-bytearray-strings-in-memory)

This is a valid question because it is asking what is the most efficient Python data structure to store large amounts of bytearrays for in-memory random access.

Answer (score 12):

> This is a valid question...

No it's not.

> ...because it is asking what is the most efficient Python data structure to store large amounts of bytearrays for in-memory random access.

It is a poor question, a very poor question. It shows no research effort, lacks information and is highly subjective. We can not answer "what is the best way to do that", because we do not what the best is *for the situation the OP is facing*. Additionally, SE tries *hard* to be book full of knowledge to be usable by everyone at every moment. Such questions might be outdated in half a year, or plain out wrong if a users is facing a completely different situation with a similar problem.

Comment: 'Guys' is not sexist - it is more often than not used as a general term nowadays. Dictionary.com says: 'Usually, guys. Informal. persons of either sex; people: Could one of you guys help me with this? '

Comment: I think he's playing on how some people instinctively treat any passing mention of a certain gender as representative of sexism.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Actually, I just could not resist to make that lame joke...

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Delete the question.

Comment: @DaveRlz Thanks, "guys" was used in that spirit.

Comment: @dbv: Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby If the question was not valid wrt SO's guidelines then one option is to delete the question instead of it hanging around.  If that is acceptable to the SO moderators then delete the question.